# What branch of psychology deals with the Framing Effect?

Tags: reference-request

What branch of psychology deals with the framing effect (Tversky and Kahneman, 1981)? Any notable related literature?

Tversky, A., & Kahneman, D. (1981). The Framing of Decisions and the Psychology of Choice. Science, 211(4481), 453-458. Retrieved September 5, 2020, from http://www.jstor.org/stable/1685855

Answer (score 3):

[Gestalt psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology) (Interpretrations of problems) and [cognitive psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_psychology) (Problem solving). If you are fairly new to these topics, Robert Stenberg's ***"[Cognitive Psychology](https://www.worldcat.org/title/cognitive-psychology/oclc/654314386)"*** is pretty simple and explains a lot of the basics of this complicated issue.

It should be noted that Tversky and Kahneman are specialist in cognitive psychology itself, and have more works on this subject; but I still recommend Stenberg's work to appreciate a lot more of these books if you are starting to learn in psychology and the likes.

Hope it helps.